# Problem with php and unity only in some Devices

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

i have this php line of codes for Updating Score of my players or creating a new record for them . this use post method to get player name and score and then update them . i use it to Update The scores , because i dont want to have one name with multiple scores in my board . **AND THIS CODE WORK FOR UNITY POST METHOD AND BROWSERS HTML**

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO scores (name, score)
VALUES ('$name', '$score')";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$sql2 = "DELETE FROM scores WHERE score < '".$score."' AND name = '".$name."'";
if ($conn->query($sql2) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record Corrected";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

and i use this code in unity to send name and score with post method .

```
IEnumerator Upload()
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", PlayerPrefsManager.GetPlayerName().ToString());
    form.AddField("score", PlayerPrefsManager.GetPlayerBestScore().ToString());

    using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post("http://gabrielexception.ir/addscore.php", form))
    {
        yield return www.SendWebRequest();

        if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
        {
            Debug.Log(www.error);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is , in some cases ( maybe 20% of phones ) name wont be updated , it just Create new record for same exactly name Over and Over . if player got 50 new record , it just create 50 records . How is it possible for this code to work 100% Correct in some phones , and work 50% correct in Others !

Comment: I can recommend you not use names like identificator field. You can use autoincremental keys. With this method, you have one number foreach user. Then you can use this field in the where condition.

A tip. If you are developing a real game, not only an exercise, be carefull with the security of your code. It accepts SQL injections. You can investigate about it and use parameters in your queries.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.